# How to concatenation string value with every line in text file Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have a large text file it contains 700k lines.
I want to concatenation or append small string "/products/all.atom" with every single line.

I tried this code

```
enter code here
import os
import sys
import fileinput

print ("Text to search for:")
textToSearch = input( "> " ) 

print ("Text to replace it with:")
textToReplace = input( "> " )

print ("File to perform Search-Replace on:")
fileToSearch  = input( "> " )
#fileToSearch = 'D:\dummy1.txt'

tempFile = open( fileToSearch, 'r+' )

for line in fileinput.input( fileToSearch ):
if textToSearch in line :
    print('Match Found')
else:
    print('Match Not Found!!')
tempFile.write( line.replace( textToSearch, textToReplace ) )
tempFile.close()


input( '\n\n Press Enter to exit...' )
```

But code is not working perfect, what i am doing here is replacing ".com" with ".com/products/all.atom" but when i run this command loop is going infinite and it writes file with 10gb of size.

Here is example what i want:

```
store1.com > store1.com/products/all.atom
store2.com > store2.com/products/all.atom
store3.com > store3.com/products/all.atom
```

[click here to check text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhF29.png)

please help me.

Comment: We tend to jump in after you've shown us your attempt to solve the problem. It should be a short script that you can post here. Include a few lines of sample data so we can see what these lines look like.

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: @SyedAashir you've included your example data, but not an example of your attempt to solve the problem. What methods have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Provide a minimal code sample to show what you're trying

Comment: @tdelaney please check now.

Comment: @daveruinseverything check now.

Comment: please fix your indentation, pretty sure that will get syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try list comprehension and string concatenation:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    print([line.strip() + "/products/all.atom" for line in f])
```

outout:

```
['store1.com/products/all.atom', 'store2.com/products/all.atom', 'store3.com/products/all.atom', 'store4.com/products/all.atom']
```

Updated solution:

Here is how you will write in new file:

```
with open('names','r') as f:
    data=[line.strip() + "/products/all.atom" for line in f]
    with open('new_file','w+') as write_f:
        for line_1 in data:
            write_f.write(line_1 + '\n')
```

Comment: It's working file is print but now how i can save this output in text file.

Answer (score 0):

```
fo=open('sta.txt','r+') # open file for read    
lines=fo.read() # reading lines in file 
fo.close()  
fo=open('sta.txt','w') # open file for Write    
for i in lines.split('\n')[:-1]:  #split the lines (using \n)and avoid last one
    fo.write(i+' hai \n') # write new lines #replace 'hai with what you need to append
fo.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The transformation is straight forward, you just do a `str.replace` of the from and to strings. Write to a temporary file so that you don't overwrite while you are still working on it and rename it when you are done.

The `file.writelines()` method takes an iterator and calls it repeatedly to get the lines to write. I used a generator that reads each line of the file and replaces the text.

```
import os

print ("Text to search for:")
textToSearch = input( "> " ) 

print ("Text to replace it with:")
textToReplace = input( "> " )

print ("File to perform Search-Replace on:")
fileToSearch  = input( "> " )

outName = fileToSearch + ".tmp"

with open(fileToSearch) as infile, open(outName, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(line.replace(textToSearch, textToReplace) for line in infile)

print("Lines replaced, do you want to overwrite original file? (y/n):")
replace = input("> ")
if replace.startswith ('y'):
    os.remove(fileToSearch)
    os.rename(outName, fileToSearch)

input( '\n\n Press Enter to exit...' )
```